# Why am I unable map JSON object data in Next.js?

Tags: json, next.js, mapping

I am trying to display some JSON data that I receive from my backend. I first have a `useEffect` which retrieves the JSON data:

```
const [backendData, setBackendData] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/userData/')
      const json = await response.json()

      // check if response is ok
      if (response.ok) (
        setBackendData(json)
      )
    }

    fetchUserData()
    console.log(backendData, 'hi')
  }, [])
```

And then in my JSX code I want to display the `_id` of the object which has a structure that looks like this:

[image]

by using this line of code:

```
{backendData && backendData.map((userData) => {
            <p key={userData._id}>{userData._id}</p>
          })}
```

I am unsure as to why this line of code doesn't work though because I don't see any output on the next.js page. I am able to receive the backend data as I see the object in my console when I log it but when I try mapping it, it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why, you have to return a value when you map in next.js so the solution would be:

```
{backendData && backendData.map((userData) => {
              return (
              <p key={userData._id}>{userData._id}</p>
              )
            })}
```

Comment: If you don't want to write return as in your first case, use ( instead of { after arrow.